# pthread bus error

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm doing an exercise. The goal is to make a program in C to crack DES encrypted password.
Right now I have the following flow of execution:

1. Load dictionary.
2. Dictionary search.
3. Brute force search of the first 4 characters.
4. Dictionary search combined with brute force (searching for
   combinations). Only dictionary words of 7-6 characters.
5. Brute force search of the first 5 characters.
6. Dictionary search combined with brute force (searching for
   combinations). Only dictionary words of 5-4 characters.
7. Brute force search of up to 8 characters.

The program works fine, but I want to improve it by using multiple
threads:
1st thread - main
2nd thread - dictionary and dictionary combined with brute force
search
3rd thread - brute force search

I've started by making a basic dictionary search thread function, but
it fails with Bus Error (Mac OS X) where it should start reading words
from the dictionary file. Same code works fine in the regular non-
thread function...

Here is the code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define MAXLINE 40
#define MAXPASS 9

/* dictionary search thread function */
void * dictionary(void * argv)
{
    /* initializing SALT */
    char salt[3];               // defining salt (length is always 2 chars + "\0")
    strncpy(salt, argv, 2);     // copying the first 2 characters from encrypted password to salt
    salt[2] = '\0';             // placing null character to make salt a string

    /* defining and initializing password */
    char password[14];
    strcpy(password, argv);
    /* defining candidate */
    char  candidate[MAXPASS];

    /* opening file */
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Can not open file.\n");
        return (void *) -1;
    }
    printf("Open file: Ok\n");
    char line[MAXLINE];
    printf("Counting words: "); 
    /* counting words the file contains */
    int ctr = 0;    // words counter variable 
    int len;        // store length of the current line
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL && line[0] != '\n')
    {
        if ((len = strlen(line)) <= MAXPASS && len >= 4)
            ctr++;  // will be real+1 when the loop ends
    }
    ctr--;          // adjusting to real words count
    rewind(fp);     // go back to the beginning of file
    printf("%d words\n", ctr);

    /* create an array of strings and fill it with the words from the dictionary */
    printf("Creating array for file contents: ");
    char words[ctr][MAXPASS];
    int i = 0;      // loop counter variable
    printf("Ok\n");
    /************************************* BUS ERROR *********************************************/
    printf("Reading file contents: ");
    while (fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL && line[0] != '\n')
    {
        if ((len = strlen(line)) <= MAXPASS && len >= 4)
        {
            line[len-1] = '\0';
            strcpy(words[i], line);
            printf("%d: %s\n", i, words[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("Ok\n");
    printf("Loaded %d words...\n", ctr);

    /* closing file */
    printf("Close file: ");
    if (fclose(fp) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Can not close file\n");
        return (void *) -2;
    }
    printf("Ok\n");

    /* starting search dictionary search */
    printf("Starting Dictionary Search...\n");
    int match = 0;
    char * encrypted;
    int n;
    for (i = 0; i <= ctr && !match; i++)
    {
        encrypted = crypt(words[i], salt);
        if ((strcmp(encrypted, password)) == 0)             // if candidate == password
        {
            match = 1;
            strcpy(candidate, words[i]);
            printf("Password: %s\n", candidate);
            return (void *) 1;
        }
    }

    return (void *) 0;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    /* if there are less/more than 1 argument, notify the user and exit with an error code  1 */
    if (argc != 2)      // first argument is always the name of the program
    {
        printf("Error 1: Wrong number of arguments\n");             
        return 1;
    }
    /* if the length of the argument is less/more than 13 characters, notify the user and exit with an error code 2 */
    int length = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (length != 13)
    {
        printf("Error 2: The length of an encrypted password should be 13 characters\n");
        return 2;
    }

    pthread_t dct;      // dictionary thread identifier
    void *status;       // thread return value

    /* creating dictionary thread */
    pthread_create(&dct,NULL,dictionary,argv[1]);

    printf("Waiting for thread to terminate...\n");
    pthread_join(dct,&status);

    //printf("Return Value: %d\n",(int)status);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code here, not on some other website. http://stackoverflow.com/ is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers; what happens when your code host shuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for posting the code on pastebin, but I'm new to stackoverflow and had trouble formatting the code...

Comment: Formatting the code is easy. You just indent a line with 4 spaces, or select the entire block and click the `{}` button in the toolbar of the editor.

Comment: I fought against the code formatting by hand for far too long before finding that `{}` button sitting in plain sight. :) I know I just ignored buttons on HTML editor widgets in the past, but this one is useful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to *guess* that this is your problem:

```
char words[ctr][MAXPASS];
```

When you're running a single-threaded program, you've got plenty of address space for the stack to grow down, libraries and program executable space to grow up, and heap in the middle.

But when you're running multi-threaded programs, each thread gets its own stack and I wouldn't be surprised if the stack space available for the threads is significantly smaller than your dictionary size. (See the `pthread_attr_getstack()` manpage on your system for details on the per-thread stack size default.)

Allocate that array with `malloc(3)` and see if your program gets further.

> ```
> char *words;
> words = malloc(ctr * sizeof(char));
> int i; // loop counter variable
> for (i = ; i < ctr; i++)
>     words[i] = malloc(MAXPASS * sizeof(char));
> ```

If you find the multiple `malloc(3)` calls introduce enough memory fragmentation, you can use some slightly-gross casting to allocate a single large block of memory and treat it identically to the multidimensional array:

```
$ cat multidimensional.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NWORDS 1000
#define WORDLEN 10

void fun(char words[NWORDS][WORDLEN]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<NWORDS; i++) {
        strcpy(words[i], "test");
    }

    for (i=0; i<NWORDS; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *w = malloc(NWORDS * WORDLEN * sizeof(char));
    memset(w, 0, NWORDS * WORDLEN * sizeof(char));
    fun((char (*)[WORDLEN]) w);

    return 0;
}
```

You'd have to use another function because you cannot *assign* to an array but when you write a function that should be passed an array as an argument it actually decays to the pointer cast in the function call: `char (*)[WORDLEN]`. (It could have been written: `void fun(char (*)[WORDLEN])` as well but I don't think that is as legible.)

I'm always a little worried when I silence a warning with a cast, as I've done here, but this does perform a single large allocation instead of thousands of little tiny allocations, which might a huge performance difference. (Test both and see.)

Comment: I know how to allocate a 2d array of int, however I am having trouble with chars. I am trying to do it like that, but it still fails:    char *words[ctr];
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < ctr; i++)
      words[i] = (char *) malloc(MAXPASS);

Comment: Thanks. Did it and it works:) char **words;
 words = malloc(ctr * sizeof(char*));
 int i;   // loop counter variable
 for (i = 0; i < ctr; i++)
  words[i] = malloc(MAXPASS * sizeof(char));